# Java Threads isInterrupted(), why this output is not appearing

Tags: java, multithreading

I am playing around with threads and found some curious output from my program that I'm having trouble understanding.
Here is my Self class:

```
public class Self {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello from main");
       
        Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
       
        if (Thread.interrupted()) {
            System.out.println("Message 0A");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Message 0B");
        }
       
        t.interrupt();
       
        if (t.isInterrupted()) {
            System.out.println("Message 1A");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Message 1B");
        }
       
        if (Thread.interrupted()) {
            System.out.println("Message 2A");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Message 2B");
        }
       
        if (t.isInterrupted()) {
            System.out.println("Message 3");
        }
       
        System.out.println("Back from where ever I was");
    }
}
```

And here is my output from the Self class:

```
Hello from main
Message 0B
Message 1A
Message 2A
Back from where ever I was
```

Why does *"Message 3"* never get printed? And why does *"Back from where ever I was"* always appear after any message related to thread t?

Comment: All your code run on the `main` thread. It is normal that "Back from where ever I was" always appears last.

Answer (score 10):

The message  `"Message 3"`
is not displayed because 'the interrupted status' of the main thread has been cleared by the call `Thread.interrupted()`. That is the key distinction between the instance method `isInterrupted` and the static method `interrupted`. The former does NOT clear the 'interrupted status'.

Check out javadoc for more details.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted()